# is their was to add loop inside in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, web, web-deployment

I tried using a template from code pen of a calendar so my goal is to add some event that has event name and start and end date.So I'm using java and using JSP to code this is the code output is coming but it's required to define indexes, again and again, I tried many ways of adding loops but getting errors

```
<%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>   

</head>
<body>
<br/>
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="ui sixteen column">
      <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%
String[] eventArray=new String[3];
String[] startdateArray=new String[3];
String[] enddateArray=new String[3];
int i=0;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/calendar","root","");
    Statement st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) st.executeQuery("select * from events");
    while(rs.next()){
        eventArray[i]=rs.getString("event");
        startdateArray[i]=rs.getString("startdate");
        enddateArray[i]=rs.getString("enddate");
        
        /*System.out.println("Event is:" +eve);
        System.out.println("Starting Date is:" +startdate);
        System.out.println("Ending date is:" +enddate);*/
    
        i=i+1;  
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
<script>
var event=[ ];
var startd=[ ];
var endd=[ ];

<%for(int x=0;x<eventArray.length;x++) {%>
event[<%= x %>]='<%=eventArray[x]%>';
startd[<%= x %>]='<%=startdateArray[x]%>';
endd[<%= x %>]='<%=enddateArray[x]%>';
<%}%>
var j=0;
even:[
{ title: event[j] ,start: startd[j],end: endd[j],}
]
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            
            defaultDate: '2020-06-28',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: [
                                { title: event[j] ,start: startd[j],end: endd[j],},
                                //{ title: event[5] ,start: startd[5],end: endd[5],},
                            //{ title: event[j] ,start: startd[j],end: endd[j],},
                            //{ title: event[j+1] ,start: startd[j+1],end: endd[j+1],},
                            //{ title: event[j+2] ,start: startd[j+2],end: endd[j+2],},
                        ]
            
        });
    });
</script>
```

so i have just added 3 events in data base so removing the comments I'm getting those 3 dates maked with events but if their are 100 events i cannot add 100 right so i need some way to solve this
please some one help me
any idea please comment so we can try
thanks in advance
thank you.

Comment: `java != javascript`

Comment: I even know that but how can I resolve my issue I tried multiple ways but none worked

Comment: _I even know that ..._ So why tag both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating 3 different arrays in `js` you can create `json-array` with `objects` and passed the same to your `events` under `fullcalender`.Some of the changes you need make in your code :

Your **javascript** code :

```
<script>
 var datas=new Array(); //declare this
<%for(int x=0;x<eventArray.length;x++) {%>

 //adding  data
    items={};
    items["title"]='<%=eventArray[x]%>';
    items["start"]='<%=startdateArray[x]%>';
    items["end"]='<%=enddateArray[x]%>';
    datas.push(items);//push data into array
<%}%>
console.log(datas)
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
          right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
            
      defaultDate: '2020-06-28',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: datas //pass same json array created
    });
 });
</script>
```

**Demo Code** :

```js
var datas=new Array();
//adding dummy data
items={};
items["title"]="abc";
items["start"]="2020-05-20";
items["end"]="2020-05-26";
datas.push(items);
//adding dummy data
items={};
items["title"]="abwc";
items["start"]="2020-06-15";
items["end"]="2020-06-28";
datas.push(items);
console.log(datas)


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

    defaultDate: '2020-06-28',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events:datas//passs the same

  });
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="ui sixteen column">
      <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clear explanation. Like I'm a beginner in web programming and I'm really interested in working to build my skills so I need some help if u can help me can some way of contact.So when ur free  u help me develop in programming
Thank a lot for the help and Explanation